# why &drupal_static is getting used with refernce?

Tags: 7

I am going through different modules and I found this &drupal_static function but exactly dont know why is getting used can any one please explain what is the purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

### function drupal_static

> Provides central static variable storage.
>
> All functions requiring a static variable to persist or cache data
>   within a single page request are encouraged to use this function
>   unless it is absolutely certain that the static variable will not need
>   to be reset during the page request. By centralizing static variable
>   storage through this function, other functions can rely on a
>   consistent API for resetting any other function's static variables.

More with examples: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7